# The use of sql%notfound on implicit cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm completely new to oracle PLSQL. Any help is appreicated.

I could not find similiar question on SO (Maybe it's too basic?)

I'm running the code from TOAD,   Oracle 11G

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
var titres%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN
    select reference, sicovam into
    var.reference, var.sicovam 
    from titres 
    where reference = '1234';
    if sql%notfound then 
        dbms_output.put_line('NOT FOUND');
    else 
        dbms_output.put_line(var.reference || '    ' ||  var.sicovam);
    end if;
END;
```

If the `Where` Clause can extract one row of data, then it will run the `else` part

If the `Where` Clause cannot extract any row, then it will display the error:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

I have tried using the basic exception handling code

```
When others then 
null;
end;
```

Then I am getting another strange result:
If the `Where` Clause can extract one row of data, then it will NOT run the `else` part or the `if` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a query inside a pl/sql block returns no rows the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception is raised immediately and execution of the block will halt. So the `if sql%notfound then` condition will never be evaluated. To catch that exception and respond accordingly,  you need `EXCEPTION` section.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
  var titres%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN
    -- In this case you have to be sure that the query returns only one row
    -- otherwise the exception ORA-01422 will be raised
    select reference, sicovam into
      var.reference, var.sicovam 
     from titres 
    where reference = '1234';  

    dbms_output.put_line(var.reference || '    ' ||  var.sicovam);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
  THEN dbms_output.put_line('NOT FOUND');    
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested your code and it works perfectly. I found the sample code from http://www.iselfschooling.com/Free_Oracle_Training/01_Basics/02_PLSQL/lesson01.html   So am I understand the usage of `sql%notfound` wrongly? I'll accept the answer after 3 minutes

Comment: @Larry With the PL/SQL `select into` statement, `SQL%NOTFOUND` will not be helpful. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS527)

Answer (score 2):

with `select into` you need to use exceptions `NO_DATA_FOUND` and `TOO_MANY_ROWS`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
var titres%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN
    select reference, sicovam into
    var.reference, var.sicovam 
    from titres 
    where reference = '1234';

    dbms_output.put_line(var.reference || '    ' ||  var.sicovam);

exception
  when no_data_found
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('NOT FOUND');
  when too_many_rows
  then
    dbms_output.put_line('2+ ROWS found');

END;
```